# How can I connect Flask-WTForms with the HTML-template for a Contact Form?

Tags: html, flask, flask-wtforms

I am new in Python and I am trying to build a contact page for my personal blog. I am pretty confused about how to connect the contact-route with the HTML-template.
Here my Python code:

```
class ContactForm(Form):

    name = TextField("Name", [validators.DataRequired("Message 1"), validators.Length(min=5, max=20)])
    email = TextField("Email", [validators.DataRequired("Message 2"), validators.Length(min=6,max=30)])
    message = TextField("Message",[validators.DataRequired("Message 3"), validators.Length(min=10, max=200)])
    phone = StringField("Phone", [validators.Optional(strip_whitespace=True)])
    submit = SubmitField("Send")
   
@app.route('/contact', methods= ["POST", "GET"])
def contact():

    form = ContactForm()


    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.validate() == False:
            flash("These fields are required")
            return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
        else:
            return "Form posted."

    elif request.method == "GET":
        return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
```

Here is my HTML-template for the contact page:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
        <p>Want to get in touch? Fill out the form below to send me a message and I will get back to you as soon as possible!</p>
        <form action="{{ url_for('contact') }}" name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" method=post>
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
              <label>Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
              <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
              <label>Email Address</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
              <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
              <label>Phone Number</label>
              <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
              <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
              <label>Message</label>
              <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
              <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div id="success"></div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="sendMessageButton">Send</button>
      </form>
       </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

What would be the best way to connect the forms in the HTML template(name,email,message,phone) with the Python-route, so that, once all the fields are filled and the button "Send" is clicked", the message "Form posted." appears? I read the Flask-documentation about WTF-forms but I am still not sure to understand how it works.
Thank you very much for every kind of suggestion.

Comment: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your contact route:

```
class ContactForm(FlaskForm):

    name = TextField("Name", [validators.DataRequired("Message 1"), validators.Length(min=5, max=20)])
    email = TextField("Email", [validators.DataRequired("Message 2"), validators.Length(min=6,max=30)])
    message = TextField("Message",[validators.DataRequired("Message 3"), validators.Length(min=10, max=200)])
    phone = StringField("Phone", [validators.Optional(strip_whitespace=True)])
    submit = SubmitField("Send")

@app.route('/contact', methods= ["POST", "GET"])
def contact():

    form = ContactForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = form.name.data
        email = form.email.data
        message = form.message.data
        phone = form.phone.data
        return "Form posted. name: {}, email:{}, message:{}, phone:{}".format(name, email, message, phone)
    return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
```

here, I simplified this code for you, now you don't need to check if it was a post or get request

```
@app.route('/contact', methods= ["POST", "GET"])
def contact():

    form = ContactForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = form.name.data
        email = form.email.data
        message = form.message.data
        phone = form.phone.data
        return "Form posted. name: {}, email:{}, message:{}, phone:{}".format(name, email, message, phone)
    return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
```

form.validate_on_submit will evaluate to true if the form passed all validators, if it didn't pass the validators, or if there was no form at all (like in a get request) this will evaluate to false, and will render contact.html

the return function is only to demonstrate that the form is being recieved and how you access the data.
instead of simply returning/printing you can do whatever you want with the data, send them to your email, post them on your blog, etc...

```
return "Form posted. name: {}, email:{}, message:{}, phone:{}".format(name, email, message, phone)
```

and this is your contact.html:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
        <p>Want to get in touch? Fill out the form below to send me a message and I will get back to you as soon as possible!</p>
        <form action="" name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" method="POST">
          {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

          <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.name.label() }}
            {{ form.name() }}
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.email.label() }}
            {{ form.email() }}
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.phone.label() }}
            {{ form.phone() }}
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.message.label()}}
            {{ form.message()}}
          </div>
          <br>
          <div id="success"></div>
          <div class="form-group">
            {{form.submit()}}
          </div>
      </form>
       </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

i have passed the parameters {{form.name.label}} and {{form.name}} using Jinja template,
[read about Jinja here](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/)

the form.name.label will show the value you passed to the field(like "name" and "message")
form.name will show the input field, same thing goes with form.email, form.phone, etc...

You would also want to print out errors beneath each field if it didn't validate,
say if someone didn't meet the required length it will print something like:

*Field must be between 10 and 200 characters long.

or

*Email incorrect

the way to do it is to check if there were any errors in each form field, if there is they would be stored in form.name.errors, and you'd have to Iterate over them if there was more than one error per field(this will only happen if you pass more than one validator check)

here is contact.html with erorr printing:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
        <p>Want to get in touch? Fill out the form below to send me a message and I will get back to you as soon as possible!</p>
        <form action="" name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" method="POST">
          {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

          <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.name.label() }}
            {% if form.name.errors %}
                {{ form.name() }}
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                {% for error in form.name.errors %}
                  <span>* {{ error }}</span>
                {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {%else%}
                {{ form.name() }}
            {% endif %}

          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.email.label() }}
            {% if form.email.errors %}
                {{ form.email() }}
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                {% for error in form.email.errors %}
                  <span>* {{ error }}</span>
                {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {%else%}
                {{ form.email() }}
            {% endif %}
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.phone.label() }}
            {% if form.phone.errors %}
                {{ form.phone() }}
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                {% for error in form.phone.errors %}
                  <span>* {{ error }}</span>
                {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {%else%}
                {{ form.phone() }}
            {% endif %}

          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.message.label()}}
            {% if form.message.errors %}
                {{ form.message() }}
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                {% for error in form.message.errors %}
                  <span>* {{ error }}</span>
                {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {%else%}
                {{ form.message()}}
            {% endif %}
          </div>
          <br>
          <div id="success"></div>
          <div class="form-group">
            {{form.submit()}}
          </div>
      </form>
       </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

notice that jinja uses {% %} for statements and {{ }} for variables, and statements also need to be closed using {% endif %} and {% endfor %}

In addition, I advice you to remove the min length requirement for name and only keep the max

I also suggest that you use validators.Email() for the email field, this will make sure the user will insert a real email.

I hope that was helpful, have a great day.